# How do I change the value of a variable based on 2 radio buttons?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable called: var rent = 100; and, using 2 radio buttons with id="02" and id="03" I want the value to be 100 when id="03" is checked and value 2 when id="02" is checked. So far with the code below, whether pressed or not the value is 2. :-(

```
var selection;
var email = 0;
var rent = 100;
var total;

if($('#select').val() == "Basic"){
selection = 15; 
}else{
    if($('#select').val() == "Highspeed"){
    selection = 30; 
    }else{
        if($('#select').val() == "Extreme"){
        selection = 60;
        }
    }
}

if($('#O1').is (':checked')){
    email = 5;
    }

if($('#02').prop ('checked',true)){
    rent = 2;
}

total = parseInt(selection + email + rent);
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pRawE/

Comment: Hi scrowler, not quite. See the var total; at the top of the screen? I gave it a value at the bottom of the screen which includes the var rent. The var total value will be displayed as part of  a <p></p> I've inserted like this: '+total+' so I don't need .html()

Comment: Ash, it's an example of how to select your radios

Comment: #select is a drop-down menu. It's cool, I got that part working. In the end the option should be part of the total.

Comment: If you just provided a HTML and explained what the hell is this for... you would get a nice answer in no-time! :) I mean... `email=5;` whattahellll

Comment: Roko C.Buljan, I know. I'm new at this!!! It's my first post!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
if ($('#O1').is (':checked')){
    email = 5;
}
```

The expression `$('#O1').is (':checked')` verifies if `#O1` is checked.

On the other hand, in this part of your code:

```
if ($('#02').prop ('checked',true)){
    rent = 2;
}
```

The expression `$('#02').prop ('checked',true)` is not verifying `#02`'s state, it is forcefully setting `#02` as checked.

So, to fix your behavior, try changing:

```
if ($('#02').prop ('checked',true)){
    rent = 2;
}
```

To:

```
if ($('#02').is(':checked')) {
    rent = 2;
}
```

**Note:** I understand your code is part of a larger context, but it is dealing with an element with id `O1` (the letter "O" and the number one), not `01`.

You should change it, as that value can easily be misread.

Comment: Hi acdcjunior #01 is a checkbox for an email option and it works perfectly as I want it to. My issue is #02 and #03 are radio buttons and if I change the code to how you showed it, var rent does not = 2, it = 100 such as the original value at the top of the screen as if the radio button is not checked when it actually is.

Comment: Both are checkboxes. I need them to be radio buttons. Ignore #01. #02 is the radio button and #03 but I don't have any code for #03 because I figure it doesn't matter. If #02 is checked rent = 2. If not, rent = 100. Sorry for the confusion guys. It's not easy to explain!!

Comment: I'd say you should keep using prop like so; el.prop('checked'); as it is more like other jQuery methods in that with just a property it gets its value, and when you add ",true" it sets the value. Read up here; http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1

Comment: acdcjunior you were right ... I had #o1 and #02, #03. Since I made them consistent it all works. LOL Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Removed the jsfiddle as people are not reading the question/answer/comments and seem to be randomly downvoting. Please notice that: **The OP's code is part of a larger context.** We do not know, and need not to know **nor should assume** that that snippet is part of an event function or not. All we know is that **the way it was checking for the property (`$('#02').prop('checked',true)`) was wrong and the id `#O1` would lead easily to errors** (as it was, as noted by his comments).

Answer (score -1):

**[IDs shouldn't start with a number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)**

So even though you use an `O` instead of a `0` on `$('#O1')`, it really shouldn't be `0` to begin with.

And using `$('#02').prop ('checked',true)`, won't work they way you want it to in an `if` statement, because it's for setting the state, not checking the state like `$('#O1').is (':checked')` is doing right before it.

You're also using `parseInt` when you update the total, but the values should all be integers at that point; so that shouldn't be necessary.

The larger problem may be that the default values never get reset when another selection is made if it's running on change. If it's running off of an event from another element, then that wouldn't be an issue.

**this might be easier**

Below solves both issues, and doesn't need to know the current state to do it on change.

html:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value"Basic">Basic</option>
    <option value"Highspeed">Highspeed</option>
    <option value"Extreme">Extreme</option>
</select>
<label for="email">email<input type="radio" name="rad" id="email"/></label>
<label for="rent">rent<input type="radio" name="rad" id="rent"/></label>
<button>click me</button><!-- something to click -->
```

jQuery:

```
var sets={Basic:15,Highspeed:30,Extreme:60,rent:100,email:0},//set defaults
    selection=sets.Basic,email=sets.email,rent=sets.rent,total;//set vars

//run on change
$('#select,input[name="rad"]').on('change', function() {//on change
    this.id==='select'?selection=sets[$(this).val()]://set select
    this.id==='email'?(email=5,rent=sets.rent)://set email
    (rent=2,email=sets.email);//set rent
    total=selection+email+rent;//update total
});

//run on click
$('button').on('click', function() {   
    $('#select,input[name="rad"]').each(function() {
        if(this.id==='select'){selection=sets[$(this).val()]}//set select
        else if(this.id==='email'&&this.checked){email=5,rent=sets.rent}//set email
        else if(this.checked){rent=2,email=sets.email}//set rent
    });
    total=selection+email+rent;//update total
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/CsDH4/

Comment: Hey, just so you know, I didn downvote your answer, and really have no idea of who did it, or why... :/

Comment: The values are being reset to the default when the variables are being declared. My first jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/ncknd/1/) , aside from being checkboxes, had that exact, resetting, behavior. My point is that is seems to be, but it was not the issue, as the OP commented.

Comment: Exactly! **You** mentioned resetting, not the OP. Just look above *"I just added this answer to make sure that a way of resetting the values to their defaults"*. --- And I said too, the fiddle having checkboxes is just a detail, its just the HTML, rename from `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"` and you'll get your radioboxes, the behavior remains unchanged: the javascript code does not need to be changed, and the question was about javascript. // my point, just changed the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/ncknd/3/

Comment: Refactoring's not a choice, and OP didn't post any HTML for you to change, or **NOT** mention resetting... Though it won't really matter, if it's firing on a click event from another element. If you want I can approach it from the same perspective, and remove the additional 33 chars, and run the function on a click event. Not really sure what exactly you want me to do, you seem to be arguing with yourself...

Comment: I refactored on `change` and added on `click`, so either way should be covered.